# Computing Slater determinants

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algorithm, physics

I need to compute [Slater determinants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant). I'm wondering if I would benefit from assigning each of my functions to a variable prior to computation. I'm working with Slater determinants, but my question goes beyond them and applies to the computation of any determinant.

Say I have functions $f_n[x]$ which are sums of complex exponentials. If I want to compute the determinant of an $N\times N$ matrix, should I use the expanded form of $f_n[x]$ or variables ($a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$, etc.), or else? Does *Mathematica* benefit from prior "simplification" of the matrix or not?

At the moment, I'm not concerned with speed because the systems I work with contain few electrons, but that will change.

Comment: You should be more descriptive in your question... give an example for the functions and the matrix constructed from your wavefunctions. It is not clear what $f_n$ refers to, what $a_i$ and $b_i$ are...

Comment: I've been RM'ited. @R.M Well, my functions can be _any_ functions, really. What I'm wondering is if Mathematica's algorithm for computing the determinant benefits from working with variables (a1,b2) rather than the whole functions.

Comment: lol! "RMiting" is a thing now? :P

Comment: @R.M I was referring to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/badges/49/copy-editor?userid=5) ;) But concerning my question, I expressly wanted to make it general, and not specific to Slater determinants. The question has to do with how MMA computes the determinant.

Comment: You will certainly benefit from simplifications in certain practically important cases, such as when your functions are polynomials times exponentials, since then Slater determinant reduces to Vandermonde determinant, which is known analytically for any finite matrix dimension. So, it is best to show us some specific example, even if your question is intended to be general.

Comment: Best would be to experiment on a few typical examples. It may be that a generic symbolic determinant with later substitution works better, or maybe it is better to start with the full expressions. If the dimension is at all significant, the first will definitely fail (hang) whereas the second approach might or might not work. Symbolic determinants for dense matrices can be that way.

Comment: When dealing with many-particle systems, it's useful to know what observables you're after. E.g., are you planning to calculate expectation values of single-particle operators in the end? For most applications you will end up not needing the whole Slater determinant. Instead it is then computationally much more efficient to work with creation and annihilation operators which are defined as the act of adding and removing single-particle orbitals from the Slater determinant. That way you end up cleverly using the orthogonality of the orbitals.

Comment: @Jens I'm computing MOs/energy spectra.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm only dealing with plane waves. The question was more of a "best practice" type than a "I need to get more juice out of it" type. Concerning best-practice, what would you suggest? (I hope I'm not too vague)

Comment: @CHM I think, this is more a mathematical question that the one about Mathematica. If your functions have some symmetries, you should be able to exploit them. I think, Jens gave a very good suggestion, I don't have much to add to what he said.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that what you are actually looking for is efficient clean computations with Slater determinants.

**1)** Michael Trott who wrote The Mathematica Guide Books has produced numerous essential examples of efficient code. So seeing how [this Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DressedMultiParticleElectronWaveFunctions/) works may get you started.

**2)** A recent package addresses this type of calculation: [web site](http://fermifab.sourceforge.net/) // [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.0872.pdf) // [source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fermifab/)

Comment: I'm having problems installing FermiFab on the mac. The author suggested a fix, which helped get past a compilation error, but now I'm having problems with a library not being found. I'll read that NB now, thanks!

Comment: @Vitaliy Kaurov  can you show more examples or information for the subject about the computations with Slater determinants.